# Binary trees - deletion

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I basically need a way of guaranteed O(log n) deletion. Can this be done with a binary tree, or is it always worst case O(n)?

What if I balance the tree everytime?

please help

Answer (score 3):

You need a balanced binary tree for the guarantee to work.
Red Black Trees are an example of the balanced tree structure and the implementation is not too hard.

[Red Black Trees (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

And here is a [nice lecture for that](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-10-red-black-trees-rotations-insertions-deletions/)..

Comment: I'd personally recommend [AVL Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) because I think they are far simpler to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a balanced binary tree, you could use the "heap"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: I agree with the heap since it's always balanced(complete)

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion)

As the wiki page above said:

*thus in the worst case it requires time proportional to the height of the tree*

which means if you can make it always balanced, you can get O(logN) for deletion